# ng-model of select not accessible in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the tabs directive from the UI Bootstrap Library (0.11) together with Angular (v1.3.0-beta.10). 
In my Tab I use a select Element and bind with a variable in my scope. If I change the value of the select element the model in the controller does not change. After a while I have tried to use the $parent scope in my select element.

```
<select ng-hide="$parent.hideDimensionPartBenchmark"
        id="dimension-part-benchmark"
        class="form-control"
        ng-model="$parent.dimensionPartBenchmark"
        ng-options="dpb.name for dpb in $parent.dimensionPartsBenchmark"></select>
```

With this attempt the model changes.

Is this the right way for model-view binding?

regards,
Marko

## Update

I have created a plunker, but there I can not reproduce the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/B5RC2Iivqkv2zzkKNFFV?p=preview

The only difference between this example an my project is, that I load a part of the site with the tabs.

Comment: Hello Marko, first i'd like to suggest do not use reference to parent.It is not recommended. Second could you give your complete html code and controller please ?

Comment: I have added a example, I will try to reproduce the problem in a smaller project.

Comment: In your provided example, i see the model update is ok